# Set Price for ERC20 Token

Tags: tokens, erc-20, etherscan, markets

I have an ERC20 Token that i have deployed and now have transferred it to about 100 addresses. Now the price shown on my Etherscan for my token is $0.00. When i search through the top ERC20token like BNB and all. They have there worth written like $16 per token.

How does a token become worth something on the etherscan ? Who decides this price and how does it fluctuate in the market ?

Comment: It's not really a question that has it'space here, but I will try to give you hints. Things only have the value you give them. So for a token, either you make people buy it and it will give it the value depending on the price you sell it (ICO?), or you can let the market decide and ask an exchange to make it tradable then the price will come from traders selling and buying it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to actually setPrices of my token?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37584/how-to-actually-setprices-of-my-token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: supply and demand.

I would assume services like Etherscan get the price either from a single exchange or an average from multiple exchanges.

The price in exchanges is simply determined by supply and demand. If people want to buy your token the price goes up. If people want to sell the price goes down. And if your token is not listed on exchanges there is no price (as nobody is buying/selling it).

Even if you peg your token to some specific Ether value (for example you get 1 token with 1 Eth) it does not necessarily give it any specific value (I guess this depends on the point of view).

Comment: How do i make an Exchange accept my coin if it doesn't have any value ? Do the exchange decide how much token value does each coin have depending on its distribution on the ICO ?

Comment: I have heard multiple things were people deposit there own money in there token. Like they pay exchanges to buy there own tokens to increase its sale and purchase.

Comment: I'd imagine exchanges accept coins in which they see potential. But that's the exchange's own business decision and we have no way of knowing how they actually decide.