# How is the price of BEP-20 determined?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, price

If I understand correctly after you create your BEP-20 token you should add liquidity and it will determine the base price of new token but what's happening next? How is the price determined afterwards when token is being transfered by many people?
Also how can you make your token in your wallet available for trade on demand by others?
Like if the token supply is 1000, and all 1000 is on my wallet then how can one buy this?
Sorry if these questions are stupid but I am new to this.

Comment: Prices are determined by the free market https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/37586.

Comment: @Ismael and how do I put my token for sale?

Comment: You can create your own contract or use an existing exchange, like uniswap or sushiswap.

Comment: I’m asking the same question myself, have you found out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping the tokens in your wallet, you send them to a liquidity pool such as pancakeswap. You set the price during this process and pair with another coin such as ethereum or Binance (BNB). So if anyone wants to buy your token they go directly to the pool exchange (pancakeswap). The pool determines the price based on supply and demand in comparison to the paired coin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but Is someone sends the token say, 10000 to the liquidity pool and sets the price. In swap only 10000 are available for people to buy. How can people buy more than that. Do you need to add liquidity again or can you sell it from your wallet directly without putting it into the liquidity pool and putting equal amount of other currency as liquidity.